# Android ActionBarSherlock gone wrong on Honeycomb / Galaxy Tab

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-3.0-honeycomb, actionbarsherlock

I've created app that works on every Android version from 2.2 but now that I tried it on my Galaxy Tab running Android 3.2/Honeycomb the app dies on runtime exception!

> 08-19 23:45:54.800: E/AndroidRuntime(29531):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{PACKAGE+ACTIVITY HERE}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: You must use Theme.Sherlock,
>   Theme.Sherlock.Light, Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar, or a
>   derivative.

but in my styles.xml I have declared as my theme

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock" />
```

and on AndroidManifest that

```
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```

What is possibly wrong? Works on all other devices!

Comment: Same problem here. Did you ever get the solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

Sorry if it sounds like a stupid answer but have you checked this:

There is a values-v11 folder for Honeycomb. So maybe you got an Exception because the styles in -v11 were still not on a Sherlock Style and you only changed the ordinary styles in values?

Maybe this helps anyone.

Comment: Worked for me! You need to check all the values folders in res for styles

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. I did not realise at all I had a v11 themes file where the theme was not set as parent.

Answer (score 0):

Change `parent="Theme.Sherlock"` to `parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock`

Sadly Android doesn't complain when specifying non-existing parents, so you don't get a compile error for this.

Comment: These are functionally the same and should not affect it either way.

Comment: Yeah he should be. @Jake Wharton, care to shed us some light?

Comment: So any news there? I have the same problem and still no solution! :-(